# ruby serial port working with hex data

Tags: ruby, serial-port

I have a Teensy that is setup to send a set of hex data.

A sample of this is the following:

383137323736

as you can see this translates to

817276

This is a part of a card i have swipped on the teensy side.

My issue right now is getting this data to show up on my console in ruby. Anything i have tried so far outputs an empty string or nothing at all.

Whenever i check the array size it returns as 1 which is correct since 1 set of digits is being sent via hex over my serial line.

The ruby code i have so far is as follows:

```
require 'serialport'
require 'rubygems'

sp=SerialPort.new "/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600
puts "HELLO"
while 1
        if sp.gets
                ar1 = []
                ar1 = sp.read.unpack('H*')

                puts ar1.length
        end
end
sp.close
```

So i am using the unpack function and H* to convert the whole set of hex numbers back to their original digits. According to Ruby doc, unpack should run through the whole set of numbers with the * at the end of H.

Can anyone lend a hand with this? Not really sure where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a way to convert a string of hex values of digits, is:

```
'383137323736'.scan(/.{2}/).map{ |c| c.hex.chr }.join
=> "817276"
```

Instead of `hex` you could use `to_i(16)`.

Two hex digits are the value of the number in ASCII. `unpack` using `H` isn't going to do what you want. Instead it'd be used like:

```
'817276'.unpack('H*')
=> "383137323736"
```

What you want is:

```
["383137323736"].pack('H*')
"817276"
```

Combining all that, instead of:

```
ar1 = []
ar1 = sp.read.unpack('H*')
```

Use:

```
ar1 = sp.read.scan(/.{2}/).map{ |c| c.hex.chr }
```

or something like:

```
str = [sp.read].pack('H*')
```

if you want a string back.

Pre-initializing `ar1` to `[]` isn't necessary since you're going to immediately overwrite its `[]` value.

Comment: So i tried your first block of code just as is to test the theory of it. I understand what it is doing and am able to get it working. I think my problem at the moment is stemming from my sp.gets and sp.read/

no data ever shows up, yet i have a serial lcd display on the rx line and i know the data is definitely coming into the raspberry pi.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have tried ar1 = sp.read.scan(/.{2}/).map{ |c| c.hex.chr } and str = [sp.read].pack('H*') and neither works. As mentioned in my previous comment i think its relating to my sp. gets or something of that nature. For some reason the ruby serial setup just does not want to receive that. Whenever we send data though it does work. The only thing i can think of so far is no handshaking but if we are only sending one set of data with one card swipe, how could that be a problem. And the other thing i am thinking is even if the data was skewed, i would at least see something.

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification to my inital code was necessary to get this fully working.

IF anyone is looking for an answer my final code is below:

```
require 'serialport'
require 'rubygems'

sp=SerialPort.new "/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600
puts "HELLO"
while sp.read

      sp.read_timeout = 50
      str1 = [sp.read].pack('H*')
      sp.write str1

end
sp.close
```

The change from before was first using the Tim Man's method of packing up hex to ASCII, but also modifying my while look to use sp.read instead of sp.gets.